# Find the number less than 2, in FOL

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

How to express that "the number less than 2 is odd" in first order logic, using only these symbols: 2, *, <, =, $\lnot$, $\land$, $\to$, $\exists$ and $\forall$ ?

Comment: There ae many numbers in $\mathbb Z$ that are less than $2$ (and some of those, such as $-42$, are not odd), so saying "_the_ number less than $2$" is not meaningful.

Comment: "the number less than $2$" is not defined in $\mathbb Z$. Do you mean $\mathbb N^*$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Here by «the number less than 2», I think they refer to the `predecessor` of 2. Maybe it's not so clear, but that's how it's exposed. So I'm looking for a way to identify the predecessor of 2 and state that it's odd.

Comment: @martin.koeberl You can use $\Bbb N^*$ if you want. Why it's not defined in $\Bbb Z$?

Comment: @piribes Did you copy the question verbatim from a book/exercise sheet? My comment was referring to the same problem as Henning, there are many numbers less than $2$ in $\mathbb Z$, but not in $\mathbb N^*$. (You have to write `$\mathbb N$` for $\mathbb N$.)

Comment: If you allow none of $\land,\lor,\to$, this seems to be impossible

Comment: @martin.koeberl right, that's my fault, the exercise says nothing about the membership of the number, forgive me. I corrected the question.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I don't really know, I suppose we could also use $\land$, $\rightarrow$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By saying "the number less than 2" they are implicitly saying that there is exactly one number less than 2 (it's called a definite description).  So, I would simply add this to the symbolization:

$$\exists x (x < 2 \land \forall y \ (y < 2 \rightarrow y = x) \land \neg \exists z\ 2 \cdot z=x )$$

Comment: Interesting but, how does this is supposed to select exactly the number $1$? I mean, why it can't be for $x$ to be $-1$, for instance?

Comment: @piribes The claim by itself does not say that it has to be $1$ ... it is merely saying that there is exactly one number below $2$ that is odd. Now, if we had more statements or axioms, we might be able to *infer* that this number would have to be $1$, but again, the statement by itself does not say that, so you shouldn't symbolize it either.

Comment: I see, so $\forall y \ (y < 2 \rightarrow y = x)$ is needed to select only one, correct?

Comment: @piribes Correct: it says that if you have any number smaller than 2, it has to equal $x$ ... which means there is only one number ($s$) that is smaller than $1$.  But if you prefer, you can also use its equivalent $\neg \exists y (y < 2 \land y \not = x)$

Answer (score 1):

"All numbers less than 2 are odd" (a false statement if the universe is $\Bbb Z$) would be
$$\forall x\colon (x<2\to\neg\exists k\colon x=2\cdot k) $$
"All numbers immediately preceding 2 in the order are odd" would be
$$\forall x\colon ((x<2\land \neg \exists z\colon (x<z\land z<2))\to\neg \exists k\colon x=2\cdot k )$$